# Help to understand what words fit in the sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, meaning, words

I am not posting the entire paragraph. Instead, this is only small part that I was confused about.

しかし、実物を手で触ることが

A.できても

B.できなくても

C.できる場合

D.できない場合

The answer is できなくても. I wonder why the answer isn't できない場合.

、人の所有物として守らなければならないものがある。文学や音楽などの作品とか、デザインや発明などである。これらのものは作った人、考え出した人の大切な財産である。実際に値段は付いていないので、売ってすぐにお金に換えることは

A.できるにしても

B.できるとなったら

C.できないにしても

D.できないとしたら

、お金や土地と同じように、「持ち主は私です」と主張することができる。

The answer is できないにしても=although cannot ...

But what is the different between できないとなったら and できないとしたら？

Answer (score 1):

できなく**ても** ("**even if** [one] cannot") here points to the contrast, or seeming contrariety between the intangibility of a thing and the necessity to protect it as private property (just as it is necessary to protect a tangible one as such):

> However, there are things which, **even if** we cannot touch them, we must (nevertheless) protect as a person's property.

できない**場合**("**if/in case** [one] cannot") is just a plain conditional with no added flavor. It can be taken as suggesting that we don't have to protect property if it is tangible!

Regarding the second question, the difference between **できないとなったら** and **できないとしたら** is less significant than between these two and the correct answer できないにしても . It's like **"if it proves impossible to..."** (or "if one proves unable to...")  v.s. **"if it is impossible to..."** (or if one is unable to...")

Answer (score 0):

But if you can't touch actual thing by your hands, we must save that. This is quite strange, you know.

×But if

○Even if

にしても have negative nuance. [example](http://www.ravco.jp/cat/view.php?cat_id=4493)

Comment: So にしても=even if (?) how about ~となったらand~としたら？ and also the difference between 場合andても?

Comment: にしても=even if ,  ~となったらand~としたら= When it become or became~？ 場合 is "in the case of".

Comment: しかし、実物を手で触ることが **できなくても/できない場合**、人の所有物として守らなければならないものがある-> why できなくても？not できない場合？

Comment: …できない場合 implies that you don't have to defend it when it's a concrete object, which is senseless.